# Echo or return a function in PHP

Tags: php, function, return, echo

I have this very simple question, but I am searching for hours now, and cannot find the answer.

With my function wzd_url() I make my urls.

For example wzd_url(2) gives me: http://www.mywebsite.com/douchedeur-glassoort

I use this function in my whole project and works fine. But know I want to use this function as follows:

```
echo = '<a href="' . wzd_url(2) . '">test</a>';
```

or:

```
function output() {
$output = '<a href="' . wzd_url(2) . '">test</a>';
echo $output;   

}

output();
```

it outputs: http://www.mywebsite.com/douchedeur-maten**test**

And I read some other articles about this subject, and they said I need to change echo to return in my wzd_url() function, but if I do that this function doesn't work anymore.

Can someone help me with this?

In this array I store some data for my pages:

```
$wzd_pages = array(
    0   => array('Intro', 'douchedeur-intro'),
    1   => array('Maten', 'douchedeur-maten'),
    2   => array('Glassoort', 'douchedeur-glassoort'),
    3   => array('Scharnieren', 'douchedeur-scharnieren', 'Scharnieren en draairichting'),
    4   => array('Deuropener', 'douchedeur-deuropener'),
    5   => array('Coating', 'douchedeur-coating'),
    6   => array('Prijs / Bestellen', 'douchedeur-prijs'));
```

With this function I make my URLs:

```
// URL  
function wzd_url($page) {
    global $wzd_pages;
    echo bloginfo('wpurl') . '/' . $wzd_pages[$page][1];
}
```

Comment: What do u mean by "doesnt work anymore" ? You are getting any error or what happens?

Comment: No it doesn't show the url anymore. But with the answer of MarkS I know now that I need to echo the function if I use return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to modify the `wzd_url();` function, because it uses `bloginfo();`, and this function prints the string. So I need `get_bloginfo();` or better: `site_url();`

```
// URL  
function wzd_url($page) {
    global $wzd_pages;
    echo siteurl('wpurl' . '/' . $wzd_pages[$page][1] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you change echo to return, your function will "return" that link but it wont show it. Then you need echo in you template for example:

```
echo <a href="' . wzd_url(2) . '">test</a>
```

In summary - when you need to move `echo` from your function to your template

Comment: Okay thanks, but when I do echo '<a href="' . wzd_url(2) . '">test</a>'; now it still gives: http://www.mywebsite.nltest

Comment: Do you get any output when you try `echo wzd_url(2);` ?

Comment: Hmm so please clarify what is the problem now exactly because I guess I am missing something

Comment: When I echo out the function with some strings around it I get a wrong result.

Comment: If I do this: echo `'test' . wzd_url(2);` my result is: `http://www.mywebsite.nltest/douchedeur-glassoort`

Comment: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/ntc-nvm here is fiddle with the code and it outputs proper href or its not what you expect?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have found the solution. It was the bloginfo function. bloginfo('wpurl') will echo the value. I need to use get_bloginfo('wpurl') which will return it.

Comment: ah I didnt expect it to echo value, nice that you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create 2 function as below :-

```
function wzd_url($page) {
global $wzd_pages;
    if(is_array($wzd_pages[$page]) && count($wzd_pages[$page])){
        $_return['url'] = bloginfo('wpurl') . '/' . $wzd_pages[$page][1];
        $_return['text'] = $wzd_pages[$page][0];
        return $_return;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

function anchor($page){

    if($url = wzd_url($page)){
?>
<a href="<?php echo $url['url'];?>"><?php echo $url['text']?></a>
<?php
    }

}
```